# Publishing a service on ArcGIS Server 10.4 when publisher and the server are working out of different folders

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-publisher, arcgis-10.4

The deployment scenario I am trying to use is: [The publisher's machine and the server are working out of different folders](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/overview-register-data-with-arcgis-server.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_781E94B0D808448EBC8CB920E2A6C133).  I have my development file share (hostname `dev.share.me` for this example) that my publishers all used to store their data.  Its structure is:

```
\\dev.share.me\ArcGIS
    \Data
        \Open
            \Mosaic1
                \Image1.tif
                \Image2.tif
                \...
            \Mosaic1.gdb
                ...
        \Restricted
            \Topic1.gdb
    \Desktop
        \Topic1.mxd
    \Services
        \Topic1.sd
```

Then on my ArcGIS Server (**NOT** `dev.share.me`, perhaps `dev.arcgis.me`, but definitely separate *disconnected* servers), I have:

```
C:\ArcGIS
    \Data
```

Which is registered using:

```
Publisher Folder Path: \\dev.share.me\ArcGIS\Data
Server Folder Path: C:\ArcGIS\Data
```

And I copy all the data from `\\dev.share.me\ArcGIS\Data` to `C:\ArcGIS\Data` on my server.  Once the data is on the server I repair the mosaic dataset using the repair function to change `\\dev.share.me\ArcGIS\Data` to `C:\ArcGIS\Data`.

Finally, I open my map file (Topic1.mxd) and

1. Click *File -> Share As -> Service*...
2. Choose *Save a service definition file*
3. Click *Next*
4. Choose *No available connection* (leave *Include data in service definition when publishing* unchecked)
5. Click *Next*
6. Click *Continue*
7. Under *Capabilities* add *WMS*
8. Click *Stage*

However, when I attempt to publish the service through ArcGIS Server Manager webapp, I get this error:

```
<Msg time="2016-03-18T10:46:47,272" type="SEVERE" code="8252" source="System/PublishingTools.GPServer" process="3816" thread="73" methodName="" machine="MYSERVER" user="" elapsed="">Instance of the service 'System/PublishingTools.GPServer' crashed. Please see if an error report was generated in 'C:\arcgisserver\logs\MYSERVER\errorreports'. To send an error report to Esri, compose an e-mail to ArcGISErrorReport@esri.com and attach the error report file.</Msg>
<Msg time="2016-03-18T10:47:05,468" type="SEVERE" code="8254" source="Server" process="3816" thread="1" methodName="" machine="MYSERVER" user="" elapsed="">The containing process for 'System/PublishingTools' job 'j0a3a8bbeeded4ef8b926c021d52d3b80' has crashed.</Msg>
```

I'm not sure how I am departing from the approach outlined in: [The publisher's machine and the server are working out of different folders](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/overview-register-data-with-arcgis-server.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_781E94B0D808448EBC8CB920E2A6C133).  Is ArcGIS Server really this failure prone, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

*It may be worth mentioning that I am also using a Web Adaptor, and AM publishing through the Web Adaptor URL, not the Server URL*.

---- UPDATE 2016/03/22 ----
Per the suggestions by @KirkKuykendall, I tuned the log level to debug, and tried again.  Now I get a stack trace in the log:

```
<Msg time="2016-03-22T12:32:23,421" type="DEBUG" code="9999" source="System/PublishingTools.GPServer" process="3816" thread="73" methodName="" machine="ASIAS-DEV-GIS" user="" elapsed="">java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:229)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
        at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.ejb.util.EJBBase.handleRequestBase(EJBBase.java:548)
        at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.ejb.impl.GPServerSyncBean.handleRequest(GPServerSyncBean.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:162)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:144)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:164)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:92)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:162)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:144)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:122)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:221)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:174)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:136)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:238)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:129)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:196)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:149)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:71)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.KeepAliveServer$Session.service(KeepAliveServer.java:213)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.KeepAliveServer.service(KeepAliveServer.java:233)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:66)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ServicePool$2.run(ServicePool.java:91)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ServicePool$3.run(ServicePool.java:120)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:215)
        ... 37 more
</Msg>
```

But I'm still stumped...  The first time I ran it, it was exactly 60 seconds after the publish request showed up in the log, so I started thinking a timeout of some sort.  But subsequent attempts showed crashes in less time, so I gave up on that...

Comment: Does the arcgis account have access privs to C:\ArcGIS\Data ?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, yes, I gave the `arcgis` account full control of `C:\ArcGIS` (including _Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object_).

Comment: Are you able to publish a mapservice that doesn't have a mosaic in it (e.g. just a simple featureclass)?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, indeed, I have been able to do that.  I have also been able to publish a map service that includes rasters (just not in a mosaic dataset).  In fact, i can even publish a service using _the very same_ rasters as the mosaic, following _the very same_ procedure above (just a different mxd)

Comment: Have you tried setting log level on the server to debug, to see if it gives more details ?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, I am not sure what you mean by _setting log level on the server to debug_.  As far as i know, it always logs all the messages and the web client can filter out which ones you see.  If that is the case, then yes, i have looked in the logs at debug level.  But if there is a way to tell the server to log more detailed messages in the first place, i'd be happy to try it...

Comment: Maybe try using the UI to change the log level.  Pretty sure it controls what gets logged to the file - it sure seems to slow thing down if you forget and leave it set at debug.  http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/about-specifying-server-log-settings.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_546FEE9709C64B66AC33EE0428A342A3

Comment: Click the "settings" button to set it.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, thanks, I tuned up the logger to `debug` and now I see a stack trace (see the update in the question above).  It seems to indicate a connection used by RMI was closed causing the service to crash.  However, I cant figure out why that would be happening...

Comment: Looks serious.  Did you try using a UNC path instead of c:\arcgis\data?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, sadly, I cannot use UNC.  This is my dev server (proving ground).  Once validated, these services will be propagated to the QA, then Production servers.  As such, if they used UNC, then they would all be referring to the same share.  Whereas the local drive path is relative to the server itself...

Comment: Do you get same behavior if you don't enable WMS capability?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, yup, same failure...  Actually had the ESRI support guys ask me to try the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug.  I worked with ESRI support to provide them with a procedure to reproduce in their environment.  If/when they decide to provide a fix for this issue, I will update this answer.  For now, I guess I'm outta luck...

> The bug has been logged and is BUG-000065570.  ...  client can also
>   discuss this Bug with their account manager and let them know that
>   issue is impacting productivity and needs to be escalated.
>   Additionally if you or your client have any other questions for ESRI
>   Support on this matter, you can always reply to this email and I will
>   try to assist. At this time our case will be marked as resolved as
>   there is no active troubleshooting for us to take